# Could not insert new outlet connection

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) y estoy siguiendo algunos manuales.
Estoy intentando conectar un `label` puesto en el `storyboard` con el código, para ello abro el **AssistantEditor** y con el secundario del ratón arrastro a la zona del código donde quiero poner este `label`, y me sale el siguiente error:

> Could not insert new outlet connection: Could not find any information
>   for the class and not showing any class named "ViewController"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El primer label si que está hecho y funciona ya que era el código de ejemplo que daba el manual, pero he intentado reproducirlo y me sale ese error.

Saludos.

Comment: Mira a ver si tienes conectado el layout con la clase.

Comment: ¿Eso se hace con el Identity Inspector que sale en la barra lateral izquierda del storyboard?

Comment: A mi me sale en la barra lateral derecha del storyboard pero sí, ahí aparece.

Comment: @Error404 en la derecha quería decir, que me he confundido jajajaja

Comment: Nada, no te preocupes. Donde pone Class ahí debería de aparecer tu clase ViewController.

Comment: Lo acabo de mirar y si que me pone en el parámetro class  la clase ViewController y he intentado hacer de nuevo lo de asociar el label con el código y me sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Vale entonces puede ser que se haya creado mal la label. Prueba a hacer un `Product > Clean` y luego un `Product > Build`. Si a pesar de esto no te funciona, intenta eliminando la label y creándola de nuevo.

Comment: Acabo de hacer el  `Product > Clean` y luego el `Product > Build` y nada, y la he borrado y vuelto a crear y nada

Comment: Mira la respuesta de @HLai aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288773/could-not-insert-new-outlet-connection

Comment: Gracias siguiendo esos pasos, que son los mismos que ha publicado @Patrick me ha funcionado, aunque me ha costado encontrar donde estaba la carpeta  jajajajaj

Comment: Me alegra saber que te ha sido de ayuda :). Yo también soy nuevo con Swift y las dos primeras opciones son las que podían ser más evidentes. Para la tercera (un poco más específica y al ver que las otras dos no funcionaban) ha sido necesario una búsqueda por nuestro amigo Google. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguramente tienes que borrar absolutamente todos los datos almacenados de tu proyecto. **Sigue estos pasos:**

1 - Cierra el proyecto.

2 - Borra la carpeta DerivedData de tu proyecto. Se encuentra en la ruta:  ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/(tuProyecto)/).

3 - Reinicia tu proyecto.

Comment: Gracias! Me ha funcionado, son los mismos pasos que ha puesto @Error404 y me ha ido

Comment: Si todos estos pasos no te funcionan, prueba a pulsar Option (Alt) mientras pulsas Clean. Borrara todo lo que tiene la carpeta Build y XCode no cogera las conexiones antiguas...